# How to generate session windows in streaming queries in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

The following code works as expected for batch, but fails for streaming queries with the infamous `AnalysisException`:

> Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

temp = [
  ('Alice', 1),
  ('Alice', 60),
  ('Alice', 160),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1112),
  ('Bob', 3),
  ('Alice', 2),
  ('Bob', 2),
  ('Alice', 3),
  ('Bob', 1)
]

temp_df = spark.createDataFrame(temp, ["user", "ev_timestamp"])

maxSessionDuration = 60 * 10 # Max session duration of 10 minutes.
client_fp_time_window = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("ev_timestamp")

rowsWithSessionIds = temp_df \
    .select("user", "ev_timestamp", lag("ev_timestamp", 1).over(client_fp_time_window).alias("prevEvTimestamp")) \
    .select("user", "ev_timestamp", 
            when(
              (col("ev_timestamp").cast('long') - col("prevEvTimestamp").cast('long')) < maxSessionDuration, 0) \
            .otherwise(1).alias("isNewSession")
    ) \
    .select("user", "ev_timestamp", sum("isNewSession").over(client_fp_time_window).alias("sessionId"))

display(rowsWithSessionIds)


sessionsDF = rowsWithSessionIds \
  .groupBy("user", "sessionId") \
  .agg(min("ev_timestamp").alias("startTime"), max("ev_timestamp").alias("endTime"), count("*").alias("count")) \
  .alias('Session')

display(sessionsDF)
```

I understand that this is because the `lag()` function is not supported for streaming queries. So the recommended alternative is to go with the `mapGroupsWithState()` approach but this is limited to Scala/Java only.

How can this be achieved in Pyspark? Or what other alternatives are available for Structured Sessioning with Pyspark?

The desired output would look something like this per batch:

```
user    sessionId   startTime   endTime count
Bob     1           1           3       3
Alice   1           1           160     5
Alice   2           1111        1112    7
```

Comment: Just curious about that part _"So the recommended alternative is to go with the mapGroupsWithState() approach"_. Where did you find this recommendation? I'm not saying it's incorrect just want to read/hear that in a wider context. Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: Basically every other suggested approach I have encountered dealt with _mapGroupsWithState()_ in one way or another. Also, the official Spark Github example for Structure Sessionization uses it too: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredSessionization.scala

Comment: Are you interested in using `lag` window function or solving a more generic problem of sessionization?

Comment: Sessionization. But I also want to perform other operations on the sessionized dataset in the later steps.

Comment: Looks like you have to use [Scala or Java](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#arbitrary-stateful-operations) then.

Answer (score 0):

Since `spark >= 3.2.0`, [`F.session_window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.session_window.html#pyspark-sql-functions-session-window) is available and it can be used for both streaming and batch. The output is slightly different than yours, instead of `sessionId` we get `session_window`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

temp = [
  ('Alice', 1),
  ('Alice', 60),
  ('Alice', 160),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1111),
  ('Alice', 1112),
  ('Bob', 3),
  ('Alice', 2),
  ('Bob', 2),
  ('Alice', 3),
  ('Bob', 1)
]

temp_df = spark.createDataFrame(temp, ['user', 'ev_timestamp_sec'])
temp_df = temp_df.withColumn(
    'ev_timestamp', F.timestamp_seconds('ev_timestamp_sec')
)
# For Structured Streaming, we have to set a watermark
temp_df = temp_df.withWatermark('ev_timestamp', '5 minutes')

sess_window = F.session_window(
    timeColumn='ev_timestamp', gapDuration='10 minutes'
)
agg_cols = [
    F.min('ev_timestamp').alias('startTime'),
    F.max('ev_timestamp').alias('endTime'),
    F.count('*').alias('count')
]
sessions_df = temp_df.groupBy('user', sess_window).agg(*agg_cols)
sessions_df.show(3, False)

# +-----+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
# |user |session_window                            |startTime          |endTime            |count|
# +-----+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
# |Alice|{1970-01-01 00:00:01, 1970-01-01 00:12:40}|1970-01-01 00:00:01|1970-01-01 00:02:40|5    |
# |Alice|{1970-01-01 00:18:31, 1970-01-01 00:28:32}|1970-01-01 00:18:31|1970-01-01 00:18:32|7    |
# |Bob  |{1970-01-01 00:00:01, 1970-01-01 00:10:03}|1970-01-01 00:00:01|1970-01-01 00:00:03|3    |
# +-----+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```